# Import/Export Dialog Disappeared in pgAdmin

Tags: postgresql, importerror, pgadmin-4, postgresql-copy

I use a PostgreSQL database on my local computer. I always import csv files via right-click to the relevant table and choosing the Import/Export Dialog. However, when I opened the pgadmin last time, there was no **import/export** option in the options. I do not know what happened to it. I, once, took a backup of files and use this backup file to migrate the database to another version of Postgres. I am not sure but I want to ask might one of the options that I selected or did not select cause this trouble?

[image]

I also tried to go in an alternative way by using `copy from 'C://path/data.csv` method and it did not work. then I tried `\copy from 'C://path/data.csv` but it did not even recognize the **\** symbol and gave an error.

I wonder what happened to Postgres or pgadmin and how can I find a solution to import my data to the Postgres database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue, looked everywhere but nothing came up on WHY this happened or HOW to fix it.

**RESOLUTION**: I was able to resolve this by [downloading the latest version of pgadmin4](https://www.pgadmin.org/download/).

After downloading, the Import/Export dialog reappeared.

Hope this helps you too!

[Import/Export Dialog - Resolved](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rQffZ.png)

Comment: yes @AndresGSM_7 after a long time of using sqlshell I decided to upgrade the pgadmin and it appeared again :) thank you